# Parse a CSV file using python (to make a decision tree later)

Tags: python, csv, decision-tree

First off, full disclosure: This is going towards a uni assignment, so I don't want to receive code.  :).  I'm more looking for approaches; I'm *very* new to python, having read a book but not yet written any code.

The entire task is to import the contents of a CSV file, create a decision tree from the contents of the CSV file (using the [ID3 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm)), and then parse a second CSV file to run against the tree.  There's a big (understandable) preference to have it capable of dealing with different CSV files (I asked if we were allowed to hard code the column names, mostly to eliminate it as a possibility, and the answer was no).

The CSV files are in a fairly standard format; the header row is marked with a # then the column names are displayed, and every row after that is a simple series of values.  Example:

```
# Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
Value01, Value02, Value03, Value04
Value11, Value12, Value13, Value14
```

At the moment, I'm trying to work out the first part: parsing the CSV.  To make the decisions for the decision tree, a dictionary structure seems like it's going to be the most logical; so I was thinking of doing something along these lines:

```
Read in each line, character by character
If the character is not a comma or a space
    Append character to temporary string
If the character is a comma
    Append the temporary string to a list
    Empty string
Once a line has been read
    Create a dictionary using the header row as the key (somehow!)
    Append that dictionary to a list
```

However, if I do things that way, I'm not sure how to make a mapping between the keys and the values.  I'm also wondering whether there is some way to perform an action on every dictionary in a list, since I'll need to be doing things to the effect of "Everyone return their values for columns Column1 and Column4, so I can count up who has what!" - I assume that there is some mechanism, but I don't think I know how to do it.

Is a dictionary the best way to do it?  Would I be better off doing things using some other data structure?  If so, what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has some pretty powerful language constructs builtin. You can read lines from a file like:

```
with open(name_of_file,"r") as file:
    for line in file:
         # process the line
```

You can use the [string.split](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.split) function to separate the line along commas, and you can use [string.strip](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.strip) to eliminate intervening whitespace. Python has very powerful [lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

To create a list, you simply use empty brackets like [], while to create an empty dictionary you use {}:

```
mylist = []; # Creates an empty list
mydict = {}; # Creates an empty dictionary
```

You can insert into the list using the .append() function, while you can use indexing subscripts to insert into the dictionary. For example, you can use `mylist.append(5)` to add 5 to the list, while you can use `mydict[key]=value` to associate the key `key` with the value `value`. To test whether a key is present in the dictionary, you can use the `in` keyword. For example:

```
if key in mydict:
   print "Present"
else:
   print "Absent"
```

To iterate over the contents of a list or dictionary, you can simply use a for-loop as in:

```
for val in mylist:
    # do something with val

for key in mydict:
    # do something with key or with mydict[key]
```

Since, in many cases, it is necessary to have both the value and index when iterating over a list, there is also a builtin function called enumerate that saves you the trouble of counting indices yourself:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(mylist):
    # do something with val or with idx. Note that val=mylist[idx]
```

The code above is identical in function to:

```
idx=0
for val in mylist:
   # process val, idx
   idx += 1
```

You could also iterate over the indices if you so chose:

```
for idx in xrange(len(mylist)):
    # Do something with idx and possibly mylist[idx]
```

Also, you can get the number of elements in a list or the number of keys in a dictionary using [len](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len).

It is possible to perform an operation on each element of a dictionary or list via the use of list comprehension; however, I would recommend that you simply use for-loops to accomplish that task. But, as an example:

```
>>> list1 = range(10)
>>> list1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list2 = [2*x for x in list1]
>>> list2
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

When you have the time, I suggest you read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to get some more in-depth knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Example using the `csv` module from [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples):

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("some.csv", "rb"))
for row in reader:
    print row
```

Instead of `print`ing the rows, you could just save each row into a list, and then process it in the ID3 later.

```
database.append(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: don't waste time and mental energy (1) reimplementing the built-in csv module (2) reading the csv module's source (it's written in C) -- **just USE it!**

Comment: Example code would help.

Comment: @blokely: reading what the OP wrote would help: """This is going towards a uni assignment, so I don't want to receive code"""

Answer (score 2):

Look at csv.DictReader.

Example:

```
import csv
reader = csvDictReader(open('my_file.csv','rb') # 'rb' = read binary
for d in reader:
    print d # this will print out a dictionary with keys equal to the first row of the file.
```

Comment: two typos in the code sample: missing . in `csvDictReader` and no closing `)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the built-in [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). Though you probably can't just use it, you can take a sneak peek at the code...

If that's a no-no, your (pseudo)code looks perfectly fine, though you should make use of the `str.split()` function and use that, reading the file line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

## Parse the CSV correctly

I'd avoid using str.split() to parse the fields because str.split() will not recognize quoted values.  And many real-world CSV files use quotes.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Example record using quoted values:

```
1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"
```

If you use str.split(), you'll get a record like this with 5 fields:

```
('1997', 'Ford', 'E350', '"Super', ' luxurious truck"')
```

But what you really want are records like this with 4 fields:

```
('1997', 'Ford', 'E350', 'Super, luxurious truck')
```

Also, besides commas being in the data, you may have to deal with newlines "\r\n" or just "\n" in the data.  For example:

```
1997,Ford,E350,"Super
luxurious truck"
1997,Ford,E250,"Ok? Truck"
```

So be careful using:

```
file = open('filename.csv', 'r')
for line in file:
    # problem here, "line" may contain partial data
```

Also, like John mentioned, the CSV standard is, that in quotes, if you get a double-double quote, then it turns into one quote.

```
1997,Ford,E350,"Super ""luxurious"" truck"

('1997', 'Ford', 'E350', 'Super "luxurious" truck')
```

So I'd suggest to modify your finite state machine like this:

- Parse each character at a time.

  Check to see if it's a quote, then set the state to "in quote"

  If "in quote", store all the characters in the current field until there's another quote.

  If "in quote", and there's another quote, store the quote character in the field data. (not the end, because a blank field shouldn't be `data,"",data` but instead `data,,data`)

  If not "in quote", store the characters until you find a comma or newline.

  If comma, save field and start a new field.

  If newline, save field, save record, start a new record and a new field.

On a side note, interestingly, I've never seen a header commented out using # in a CSV.  So to me, that would imply that you may have to look for commented lines in the data too.  Using # to comment out a line in a CSV file is not standard.

## Adding found fields into a record dictionary using header keys

Depending on memory requirements, if the CSV is small enough (maybe 10k to 100k records), using a dictionary is fine.  Just store a `list` of all the column names so you can access the column name by index (or number).  Then in the finite state machine, increment the column index when you find a comma, and reset to 0 when you find a newline.

So if your header is `header = ['Column1', 'Column2']`  Then when you find a data character, add it like this:

```
record[header[column_index]] += character
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what happens when there are quotes in the original data, resulting in csv input like `Colt,45,"owned by John ""Quick Draw"" McGraw"` ... that finite state machine gets rather complicated.

Comment: So now your finite state machine appears to need a 1-byte lookahead buffer ("and the next character is a quote") which is not a good look -- the decision making process should requite ONLY a current state and ONE input character. BTW why are you egging the OP on to write a FSM when it appears the purpose of her exercise is scripting a decision tree, not low-level byte-bashing?

Comment: The CSV module's method does `parse_add_char(self, c)` in http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Modules/_csv.c when in QUOTE_IN_QUOTED_FIELD state, (same as my method).
Just showing all the problems with implementing a CSV parser.  OP says: "At the moment, I'm trying to work out the first part: parsing the CSV"
If the OP is allowed to use the CSV module, then great.  Although if she uses the CSV module the header's first value won't come out right because it's "commented out" with a #.  So that indicates to me, that part of the project is writing a parser.

Comment: Sorry, actually, their method is look behind.  If in quote, and current is quote, etc...  Your'e right John.  Updated the answer.

Comment: `123,"",456` is quite valid ... you can get that quite easily when the writer has been told to quote all strings and is fed a zero-length string. In any case the reader MUST read that as an empty field. Second point: how difficult is it to test `if field[0].startswith("#"):`? Not very. DOESN'T indicate requirement to write parser.

Comment: I agree John, writing a parser is definitely the hard way.  The OP should use the built in CSV module.  If she can't because it's a uni project where you need to show knowledge of writing a parser, this answer shows many caveats she'll have to deal with.  Thanks for helping flush them out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about the builtin csv module that @Kaloyan Todorov talks about, but, if you're reading comma separated lines, then you can easily do this:

```
for line in file:
    columns = line.split(',')
    for column in columns:
        print column.strip()
```

This will print all the entries of each line without the leading a tailing whitespaces.

Comment: """I don't know too much about the builtin csv module""" ... about time you remedied that deficiency ;-)

Comment: Totally agree. Spent a good hour or so last night reading the docs. Time well spent.